# A small script about wget

Tags: linux, shell-script, wget

I want to download an image file called `mch_aktuell_gross_20141229_79514688.gif` (basically a forecast gif) from `www.meteoradar.ch` Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
    wget \
      --recursive \
      --no-clobber \
      --page-requisites \
      --html-extension \
      --convert-links \
      --domains meteoradar.ch \
      --no-parent \
               www.meteoradar.ch/bilder/mch_aktuell_gross_20141229_79514688.gif
```

So I had `403 Forbidden` error earlier, but now it works. My question is: Was this because I had used it too excessively?

Second, is the script ok, are there any unnecessary lines or any that are missing? Also when you know a better way, please feel free to share it.

Comment: Does it make sense to use `--recursive` when you're targeting an image file? I think it's useful only for HTML-type files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As its name says, `403 Forbidden` means that the server denied permission to access to that URL. Without knowing more about the server, it's not possible to tell why your earlier requests were denied and why it works now. It's up to them whatever reason they had due to your excessive use, or possibly a temporary problem due to maintenance.

Since it looks like you only want to download a single `.gif` file,
many of the options are unnecessary,
in fact most of them,
reducing the script to simply:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget --no-clobber www.meteoradar.ch/bilder/mch_aktuell_gross_20141229_79514688.gif
```